Deprecated Java methods not showing as strikethrough in Visual Studio Code
I have this Java method:
/**
 * Old method is deprecated.
 * @deprecated Use {@link #newMethod()} instead.
 * @return boolean
 */
@Deprecated
public static boolean oldMethod() {
  return false;
}

and then later on:
boolean result = oldMethod();

In the VS Code editor, the oldMethod() doesn't show with strikethough like it does in the NetBeans (and other decent IDEs). Oddly, it does show as strikethrough in the popup code completion, but not in the final code.
I also tried calling the method from a different class, and it still has the same issue:
public class Class2 {
  void example() {
    Class1.oldMethod();
  }
}

I'm using the Apache NetBeans language server extension - however I have the same behaviour when using the ones from Oracle, Red Hat and Microsoft. Also, I checked the "Editor: Show Deprecated" setting and it is turned on. Why is it not shown?

Are you calling it from a deprecated method? (In a similar situation in C#, calling one deprecated/obsolete method from another doesn't issue warnings etc, as it's quite common when a whole set of methods is made obsolete at the same time.) If you're calling it from a non-deprecated method/class/module, that's a different matter. What happens for deprecated methods from the base package, e.g. calling new Date(124, 7, 31)?

No, I'm calling it from a non-deprecated class and method (see updated original question)

Hello, is the extended version you are using the latest version? For example, Language support for Java ™ for Visual Studio Code. Does Linter have a hint for deprecations turned on?

I have also tested "editor.showDeprecated": true was not working for me.
After playing around with VS Code configurations, I have found the solution.
Solution: Update the .vscode/settings.json of your Java Project to have editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations that you can use to do the customization on the semantics.
Screenshot of the settings.json location that will be present in your project:

settings.json:
{
  ......

  "editor.showDeprecated": true,
  "editor.suggest.showDeprecated": true,
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": {
      "*.deprecated": { 
         "strikethrough": true
      }
    }
  }
}

Screenshot of the Java code:

As soon as you use @Deprecated annotation, it will put strikethrough.

That did it! Thank you - I can't believe this doesn't work "out of the box" with the various Java language servers. BTW, I made this change to my user settings.json so that it would affect all of my projects.

The deprecated tag will only apply the strikethrough on the final code if you are accessing the method from a different class/module. The java Deprecated description states, "A module being deprecated does not cause warnings to be issued for uses of types within the module."(Oracle Documentation) For example, if I were to create a class with a deprecated method like you said,
public class Class1 {

@Deprecated
public static boolean oldMethod() {
    return false;
}
public static void run() {
    boolean result = oldMethod();
}

then calling oldMethod() would not result in a visual strikethrough. However, if I were to create another class as such,
public class Class2 {

public static void run() {
    boolean result = Class1.oldMethod();
}

}
then it will visually result in a strikethrough: Class1.OldMethod().

The OP is deprecating a method, not a module, so your reasoning does not apply.

I tried this, and still no strikethrough - see edited details on original question.

@Dave Could it perhaps be the color theme you're using? If you're using a custom theme it's possible that it may not have strikethroughs as a display option. Maybe try switching to a different theme and seeing if they still do not appear? Thanks!
